# getting error- ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle

```
Select * from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id and 
case 
when t1.id in (select t2.id from table2)
then t1.valid_to_ts > sysdate and t2.valid_to_ts>sysdate
else
t1.valid_to_ts>sysdate.
```

getting error-

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: I think you're thinking of `CASE` as a flow control operator, which it isn't. It's used to produce a value, and something like `SELECT a < b` is not valid in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION`s to implement the logic of the case:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
   AND t1.valid_to_ts > SYSDATE
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE t1.id IS NOT NULL
   AND t1.valid_to_ts > SYSDATE
   AND t2.valid_to_ts > SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Álvaro González said in a comment, you can't use a case expression as a flow control operator. You *can* use a case expression in a `where` or `on` clause, but only by making it generate a value which you then compare with something else, which can be awkward, so it's usually better not to. You can usually replace the logic you're trying to implement with simple Boolean logic.

In this case you're already joining to `table2` so your subquery isn't needed; you can use a `where` clause to see if a matching record was found - preferably checking for a not-null column other than ID, so this example will only work if `valid_to_ts` is not nullable:

```
select * from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.valid_to_ts > sysdate
and (t2.valid_to_ts is null or t2.valid_to_ts > sysdate)
```

If `t2.valid_to_ts` is nullable then you should use a different not-nullable column instead; unless you want to include values with no valid-to date - but you aren't doing that for `t1.valid_to_ts`.

If you try to check that in the `on` clause then you won't filter out IDs which do exist in `table2` but with an earlier date.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9da30b1cc9bc71a8c63f26e294e37b38), including an on-clause version which gets the wrong result (as far as I can tell from your starting query anyway).

For the demo I've assumed that the `_ts` columns are dates, since you're comparing with `sysdate`; if they are actually timestamps (as the suffix might suggest) then you could compare with `systimestamp` instead.